# Using array as tuple member: Valid C++11 tuple declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, clang

The code below compiles fine with G++ 4.7.2:

```
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<float,int[2]> x;
```

With clang++ 3.2, however, the following error is produced:

**error: array initializer must be an initializer list.**

If I remove the `float` type from the tuple declaration, the error disappears. Is the above tuple declaration valid?

(*$CXX -std=c++11 -c file.cpp*)

Comment: GCC non-standardly allows structs that contain arrays to omit the outer braces in initialiser-list syntax without an `=` sign. I think you're not allowed to do tuples of arrays because arrays are not assignable.

Comment: Tonight I can't repeat the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in the Standard that forbids your declaration. However, you will run into problems as soon as you try to initialise, copy, move or assign your tuples, because for these operations, all member types of the tuple must be able to be used as initialisers, copy-constructible, copy-assignable and move-assignable, respectively (§20.4.2.1). None of this is the case for arrays.

You will be better off using `std::array` instead of C-style arrays:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
std::tuple<float,std::array<int,2> > x;
```

Comment: Hmm. If all those things are not possible for arrays, do we really think that the declaration is valid? Isn't at least being CopyAssignable/MoveAssignable likely to be a mandated requirement of the member types?

Comment: Okay the rules do all appear to be localised to individual operations (20.4).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe it's not an explicit requirement by the Standard (same situation as for vectors), because the Standard defines the requirements per operation (e.g. CopyConstructible is only required when the copy constructor of the tuple is used). But if we had _concepts_, then you'd probably be right.